# How can I animate an element from a static layout position to an absolute layout position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form and inside this form a button. Initially the button is statically positioned at its default position based on usual layout. On an event (in the example below, button click) I want to move it to the center of the form through animation and during this animation doing a horizontal flip (using scale transform) and when the animation is in the middle (when the rendered width is 0) changing the contents of the button to a paragraph that once loaded will show an animation probably done with svg and a link.

This snippet does a part of what I want (everything until the second part of the flip with changing the contents and resizing the button to be bigger), but without an initial static position from which to start the animation:

```js
var form = $("form")
var button = $("button")

button.on("click", function(){
  var x = (form.outerWidth() - button.outerWidth()) / 2;
  var y = (form.outerHeight() - button.outerHeight()) / 2;

  button.css({
   transform: `translateX(${x}px) translateY(${y}px) scaleX(0)`
  });
})
```

```css
form {
  background: #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button onclick="return false;">Do something</button>
</form>
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/silviubogan/L1ogpf6a/)

How can I achieve what I want in the most correct manner? Please note that the rest of the form should remain in place.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it was very clear to me. Where will the button be at the end? To confirm: the button is static at the beginning and at the end it will be absolute inside the form?

Comment: The `position` cannot be animated. Frankly, though if it's a transition/animation, it would make sense to position the element absolutely to start with and adjust the position **values** as part of the animation.

Comment: @Azametzin Yes.

Comment: @silviubogan have my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways you can do this. First is using `setTimeout` ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)) with 1000ms as a parameter, since your css animation lasts 1 second, and a callback function that displays the SVG. The second is using jQuery `animate` ([reference](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)) instead of css, and using the parameter `complete` to show your SVG. Since you are already using css for the animation, let's go with the first option:

```
button.on("click", function(){
  // hide button
  window.setTimeout(transform2, 1000);
})

function transform2() {
  // change contents
  // resize button
}
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eynL91qu/

Comment: Your answer helps but there are some things missing. 1. Initially, the button is statically positioned. 2. If the user resizes the window, the button should remain in the center of the form which is getting wider when the viewport gets wider. 3. The onresize event of the window does not resize the button well, sometimes it jumps a little too down or too to the right. Thank you.